# How to increase value of tcbhashsize parameter in OS X

Tags: network, macos, tcp

I am running OS X 10.11 - El Capitan. I am trying to tune my TCP setting for better network / Internet performance. Most of the settings I have been able to modify permanently through **/etc/sysctl.conf** configuration file.

I am trying to modify the value of **net.inet.tcp.tcbhashsize** to increase the number of TCP connections served and improve TCP lookup speeds. In Free BSD, it can be modified through /boot/loader.conf, but this file does not appear to exist in OS X.

**How can this value be modified in OS X?**

Answer (score 1):

`sysctl` is the tool of choice for this. `sysctl net.inet.tcp.tcbhashsize` will tell you its value, and `sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.tcbhashsize=new_value` will set the value. However on my system I got the error `sysctl: oid 'net.inet.tcp.tcbhashsize' is read only` when I tried to set the value – no idea if it's possible to set this value in some way without compiling and running your own kernel.